# excel powerpivot update error "object was not found in the cube"

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerpivot

I have an PowerPivot file that pulls data directly from a SQL data warehouse. Next it is fed into pivot tables. When I try and update I get the following error:

***Query (20,3916) The level '&[Desktop]' object was not found in the cube when the string, [OfficeFlatFile].TopicLevel2Name]&[Desktop], was parsed.***

I checked my data source and found that the member "Desktop" was no longer available (no surprise there). But I can't get the file to update now. I tried updating the PowerPivot data connection first but that didn't work either.

This is the most recent info I could find, and it doesn't help. 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/756691/powerpivot-data-could-not-be-retrieved-from-the-exteral-data-source

Does anyone know a solution apart from rebuilding the file?

Answer (score 4):

Removing the "." in the column's name worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `.` in column names that are in the join. [Reference](http://jakubka.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/excel-powerpivottabular-error-dimension.html).

Answer (score 2):

You know, xlsx (xlsm) files are set of xml files zipped.

Try to open your Excel file with WinRar (7zip, etc) program. 
Then go to xl/pivotTables folder. There you should find pivotTable1.xml file.
Then manually delete corresponding item from the .xml

Then save the changes you made and open your Excel file with the pivotTable.
Since you manually deleted the "Desktop" item there will be no error.

Comment: Interesting idea, tried it and hopefully didn't break anything. Got past the error but excel had to recover. Not an ideal solution for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error:
The query did not run or the Data Model could not be accessed. Here's the message we got:
Query (x,y) the level '<column Name.' object> was not found in the cube when the string  was parsed.

Solution:
If there is a Slicer connected to the pivot table, disconnect it from the pivot table and remove all filters from the pivot table.
If there is not Slicer connected to the pivot table, just remove all filters from the pivot table.
Please check in the database if the values in the filter column (of the pivot table) have changed. If you have the older working version of the pivot table report, compare it to check the difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I found up to now is to use your previous working model (the one which worked fine before the update) and find all the pivots where you were filtered on "Desktop". Set these filters to "All" and then run your update.

This way you don't lose your pivot table, which sometimes is a big rework to rebuild, specially when you had charts and other dependencies linked to such pivot.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had many sheets with power pivot reports.

one of them caused the error.

removing this excel sheet and setting filters to all in other reports solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used the option of clear filter in Pivot table analyse tab and after that this error is solved